# UI assets resolution for different iPhone Sizes including iPhone 6+, iPhone X, iPhone Max

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am developing an app which should be run on all the latest iPhone models available including iPhone X, iPhone XR, iPhone 8 plus etc. However, I am confused about the sizes for 3x images since I google about it and I got 3 different sizes for iPhone X: 1125 x 2436, iPhone 8 plus:   1080 x 1920 and iPhone max: 1242 x 2688.

What size should I put in Xcode Assets for 3x?

Answer (score 0):

The 1x, 2x and 3x images are to handle different PPI (Pixels Per Inch). For different devices, based on PPI the respective images will be shown. You can find more information here.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/

Let's say your original image is 100x100 then your other images should always be 200x200(2x) and 300x300(3x).

Comment: I am just asking for 3x images, how would I put 3x images which would cater all 3x sizes including 8 plus, iPhone X, iPhone max ?

Comment: It doesn't depend on different iPhones or resolution. If your original image is 100x100 then 3x will always be 300x300. And the image will be visible in 8 plus etc. If you want to show image based on device model (not recommended) then you need to read device model and select image through code.

Comment: It is confusing, what if I put images of only 3x. How would the processor judge whether the 3x image is multiple of 3 of the original image i.e 1x and 2x respectively.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Then on the lower ppi devices the image will be downscaled. And it is a both cpu and memory incentive operation. Also downscaling sometime reduces the overall image quality (if you are pixel perfect kind of guy) like image with rounded corner border. If you want to use an image independent of ppi use a vector image.

Comment: For 3x would I go with 1125px × 2436 which is the size of iPhone X, or general 3x resolution that is 1242 x 2208. In fact, I had all the slicing done for 1125px × 2436 at the moment, would this size work on the available sizes of 3x?